# Error : 'AnyObject?' is not identical to 'AnyObject'

Tags: swift, uiactivityviewcontroller, vcf-vcard

I am trying to share the contact .vcf file using UIActivityViewController. But I am getting 'AnyObject?' is not identical to 'AnyObject'

Below is my line of Code :

```
let dirs : [String]? = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.AllDomainsMask, true) as? [String]
        if ((dirs) != nil) {
            let dir = dirs![0]; //documents directory
            let path = dir.stringByAppendingPathComponent("\(person.name).vcf")
            let text: NSString = person.contact as NSString

            text.writeToFile(path, atomically: false, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil);

            let objectsToShare = ["Send", NSData.dataWithContentsOfMappedFile(path)]
            let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
            self.presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
```

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `let objectsToShare = ["Send", NSData.dataWithContentsOfMappedFile(path)!]`

Comment: I am getting this error for objectToShare variable. Which stores the content of the vcf file.

Comment: Error is solved. But can you please help me with this. I am trying to attach the vcf file to UIActivityViewController. But it's not attaching and file. Please help.

Comment: No sorry, don't know.

Comment: @AnkitaShah, please open another question regarding opening a file with UIActivityViewController. And someone will help you with the issue.

Answer (score 3):

The character `?` is a type modifier.  You start with `AnyObject`, write `AnyObject?` and you have a new type of 'Optional AnyObject'.  That is a distinct type from `AnyObject`.  Since Swift is strongly typed, you can't put an `Int` where a `String` is expected nor can you put an 'Optional AnyObject' where an `AnyObject` is expected.

Of course, return values have types too.  You are likely invoking a function that returns an 'optional X'; if you try to use that where 'X' is expected, you'll get a type error - as you described.

If the error is with `NSData.dataWithContentsOfMappedFile(path)`, then the solution is not to simply add a `!` (operator to unwrap the optional value but CRASH if the value is `nil`).  You should use:

```
["Send", (NSData.dataWithContentsOfMappedFile(path) ?? "default")]
```

which will use the `NSData` value if it exists, otherwise `"default"` (you decide what to use, if anything).

Comment: I am getting this error for objectToShare variable. Which stores the content of the vcf file.